# The set of all normal operators on a Hilbert space is not strongly closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I need an example to show that the set of all normal operators on a Hilbert space is not strongly closed. Also I know that strong operator topology and strong* operator topology coincide in the set of all normal operators, so could I conclude that this set is not strongly* closed?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a concrete example in my head right now.

But here is the fact: the strong limits of normal operators are precisely the *subnormal* operators.

**Added much later:** here is a path to show the above. One can show

- unitaries are wot-dense in the unit ball
- because the unit ball is convex, its sot and wot closures agree

The above then says that we can do the following: start with the unilateral shift $S$, which is subnormal. Construct a net $\{U_j\}$ of unitaries with $U_j\to S$ wot. Then construct a net $\{Q_k\}$ where each $Q_j$ is a convex combination of some $U_j$, and $Q_k\to S$ sot.

Comment: Is it closed under operator norm topology?

Comment: Yes, of course.